# Invalid JSON string, cannot post to c# web api?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I got this JSON string, what is wrong with it? I can run it through several online JSON testers and they all say OK. But when this is posted to my c# web api through entity framework my post body is null. Any ideas?
This is the POST function:

```
public void Post([FromBody]List<AIM.RunningProcess> list_runningprocesses)
{
    if (list_runningprocesses == null) return;
```

This is the JSON string:

```
[
    {
      "PSComputerName":  "eetpcx31v.admin.eetp.local",
      "ProcessName":  "AcroRd32.exe",
      "ProcessID":  14240,
      "CommandLine":  ".C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe. .C:\\Users\\jmetzler\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Temporary Internet Files\\Content.Outlook\\VG2QRLL8\\Pöyry_RevealingFlexibilityValueStudy_Proposal_v2_0.pdf.",
      "CreationDate":  "Oct 24 2013 14:21:09",
      "Username":  "jmetzler",
      "RemoteIP":  null
    }
]
```

Obviously it fails because of the CommandLine property. The database column property for 'commandline' is varchar(8000). This is the 'RunningProcess' class.

```
public partial class RunningProcess
{
    public string PSComputerName { get; set; }
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public string ProcessID { get; set; }
    public string CommandLine { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string RemoteIP { get; set; }
}
```

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RunningProcess>>(json)` works for me (where `json` is your JSON string). Why do you say "Obviously it fails because of the CommandLine property"? I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: `ProcessID` could be an `int` (it's a number in the JSON), but otherwise your class looks fine to me, as does the JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Generate your C# class with http://json2csharp.com/. The class in the answer is generated from the same site.

From JSON your class should be like:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string PSComputerName { get; set; }
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public int ProcessID { get; set; }
    public string CommandLine { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string RemoteIP { get; set; }
}
```

since your `ProcessID` is `int`.

Comment: You also changed `CreationDate` to `string` and `RemoteIP` to `object`. I think these are unnecessary and undesirable changes.

Comment: @TimS., you are right, I just overlooked those, from the generated code.

Answer (score -1):

if im getting your problem correctly try changing the JSON string to:

```
{list_runningprocesses:
[
{
  "PSComputerName":  "eetpcx31v.admin.eetp.local",
  "ProcessName":  "AcroRd32.exe",
  "ProcessID":  14240,
  "CommandLine":  ".C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe. .C:\\Users\\jmetzler\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Temporary Internet Files\\Content.Outlook\\VG2QRLL8\\Pöyry_RevealingFlexibilityValueStudy_Proposal_v2_0.pdf.",
  "CreationDate":  "Oct 24 2013 14:21:09",
  "Username":  "jmetzler",
  "RemoteIP":  null
 }
]
}
```